# Magento 2.2.3 is not working with PHP 7.1.11

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.2.3

I have tried to install magento 2.2.3 in php 7.1.11 version. it successfully installed but now issue is admin and front CSS-js are not working.

I have tried so many solutions which are available on net for editing xml file and other removing cache. but its not working.

please help me.

Comment: Could you please post a  screenshot  and error log which you are facing ? -

Comment: I use php 7.1.15 and its work for me.

Comment: Please mention error that you are facing in php 7.1.11 ?

Comment: Did you deploy static content?

Comment: Are you missing a required .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see no styles, you could just verify your permissions are set properly.

```
cd /var/www/html/ && sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && sudo chown -R :apache . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
```

Unless I misunderstood your question, this might solve the pages rendering correctly.

Comment: I'm inclined to second this comment's suggestion.  Check user/groups, as well as permissions match up according to the documentation for that version.

Answer (score 0):

Hello user you need php version 7.0.2 for latest magento 2.2.3

Comment: No,not require to less upgrade.

Comment: Misleading advice.  I run 2.2.3 with php 7.1.15, which would be a much better suggestion than an older version.